# Solr term search not searching all values from multifields value

Tags: solr, solr4

I have solr field

```
<field name="AllTitles" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time -->
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Example of Value for AllTitles entered is

```
AllTitles: [ "Anything", "wuhan coronavirus", "anything" ]
AllTitles: [ "wuhan coronavirus", "anything", "anything" ]
```

It searches from first index but if any matching term on index other than 1st then it's not searching

For example when I search

```
q="wuhan coronavirus"
```

I get 2 results. When I search using field name "AllTitles"

```
q=AllTitles:"wuhan coronavirus"
```

I get 7 results correctly.

Can anybody help me identifying the issue?

Comment: Try specifying AllTitles in df parameter and for better results use qf in edismax and boost using per field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your SolrConfig.xml check what field has been defined in the "df". In the below example it is "text".

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <int name="rows">10</int>
     <str name="df">text</str>
  </requestHandler>
```

Second, in the schema.xml or managed-schema, whichever you are using, make sure you have copied "AllTitles" to "text". Like this,

```
<copyField source="AllTitles" dest="text"/>
```

You might as well test it by adding "AllTitles" to your "df" parameter when you query, before doing all these, like raghu777 has mentioned.